# Windows + Ubuntu Triple Boot — Keyboard doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, keyboard, grub

I have a triple boot of Windows 7, 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.2. I had to reinstall Windows because of corrupted drivers that could not be fixed manually. After I finished the install, I booted into Ubuntu LiveUSB and ran Boot-Repair as I usually do. It picked up my OSes and gave me the grub screen. Here my keyboard works fine--I am able to select any OS. However, upon booting into Windows 7 my keyboard and mouse stop working. Sometimes the LEDs will be on but the keys do not "record" on touch. It forces me to reset the PC. This is where it gets weird, because after a reboot into Windows 7 the keys start to work.

The keyboard works in the other two OSes though, with or without a secondary boot. I have tried just about everything I could find from others who have the same issue, that includes:

- Changing boot order to the Windows drive & changing back to the drive with grub on it
- Reseting CMOS.
- Turning OFF USB Legacy support
- Turning ON USB Legacy support
- Turning OFF/ON xCHI options or changing it to AUTO
- Editing my grub.cfg and changing the GRUB_TIMEOUT from 10 to 20
- Rerunning Boot-Repair in Ubuntu LiveUSB and within my actual Ubuntu install
- Power off the system entirely, switch off the PSU, press the power button for 5 seconds, take out the CMOS battery, press the switch on my surge protector and let it sit for an hour before hooking it all back up and turning on the PC again
- Unplug the keyboard/mouse, reboot and plug them into another 2.0 USB port OR even a 3.0 USB port
- Tried four different keyboards and mice
- Reinstalling Windows 7 with and without UEFI support

Here are some things that "work":

- Pressing F11 and selecting Windows 7's drive manually at BIOS screen (without going to grub selection)
- Booting into Windows 7 **after** a reset/reboot (2nd reboot)

I have been trying to fix this for nearly two weeks now, and hard reseting to get a "repair Windows 7 or continue as normally" screen is frustrating and will eventually lead to a corrupted Windows install, so I came here in a last ditch effort.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

[Repost from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906370/windows-ubuntu-triple-boot-keyboard-doesnt-work-in-windows-7) per suggestion.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I believe I found the solution with some help from another!

My keyboard and mouse does **not** come with drivers. I just let Windows install what it wanted and thought that was all it needed. However, after trying countless different things, I finally went to my motherboard manufacturer's website, went to support and then drivers.

I installed the Chipset it had and the latest 3.0 USB driver even though I was having trouble with the 2.0 ports. After both were installed, I turned off my computer completely and let it sit for a while. After I turned it on for a cold boot and went into Windows from the grub screen as usual. This time, however, the keyboard and mouse worked right off the bat! When I logged into the computer, Windows' driver installer popup came up and showed a few things being installed and then it was all done.

If anyone else is out there having this problem, with or without a dual or triple boot, I urge you to go get all the drivers for your motherboard and install them all and then reboot properly.

This headache has been solved!